# Can't change TextView color

Tags: java, android, textview

I need your help.

I want to change the color of TextViews in code, but get some difficulties, because nothing happens.

I've declared a TextView field in MainActivity and assigned my text object from layout to it. Then I call some method, that makes some calculation and writes the result into that textView object. When I catch an exception in this method, I'd like to change the color of my textView, but I don't get it. What should I look for to fix it?

Btw, when I try to change color in the onCreate method, it works well. Exceptions' catch block implements well too because I see that by other commands of that block. The Scale method works correctly if nothing throws any exceptions from it.
Tried to find a similar problem, but guess I'm too far from the right way.

```
private TextView outputText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    outputText = findViewById(R.id.outputText);

    //this code works fine
    outputText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, getTheme()));

    scale();
}

public void scale() {
    try {

        //some command that can throw an exception

    } catch (Exception e) {
            
        //this command doesn't work
        outputText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, getTheme()));
    }
}
```

UPD.1

here's code of the Scale method:

```
public void scale() {
    try {
        outMin = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(outMinField.getText()));
        outMinErr = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        outMaxErr = true;
        outMinField.requestFocus();
        outputText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, getTheme()));
    }

    try {
        outMax = Double.parseDouble(String.valueOf(outMaxField.getText()));
        outMaxErr = false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        outMaxErr = true;
        outMaxField.requestFocus();
        outputText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, getTheme()));
    }

    //inMin & inMax gives another method
    double out = (outMax - outMin) / (inMax - inMin) * (in - inMin) + outMin;
    outputText.setText(String.format("%.2f", out));
    outputText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.outputColor, getTheme()));
}
```

I know that I get an exception because I see a focused text input field I have trouble with.

Comment: It is not good practice to write code inside catch exception ,add the code  for scale it will help to guide for better implmentaion.

Comment: Are you sure, you're getting an exception?

Comment: @Vishal, Yes, I'm sure, becuase catch block sets the relative input text field focused and I can see it.

Comment: @EmadSeliem, Done, thanks for suggestion.

Comment: but the `scale` method changes the view color tiwce . After you caught an exception and set the view color to `errorColor`, the `scale` method continue its execution and reaches the last line where you set color to `outputColor`.

Comment: @frumle, omg, yeah. You're right! Thank you for paying my attention!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any serious problems in your code, but I would suggest the following

```
public void scale() {
    boolean error = false;
    try {
        callThatMayThrowAnException();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        error = true;
    }
    Log.d("ViewColor", "Exception thrown: " + error);
    if(error)
       outputText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.errorColor, getTheme()));
}
```

Now you can see in `LogCat` whether you caught an exception or your `callThatMayThrowAnException()` succeeded. If this will not help (error is caught but the view color has not changed) try to clean your project in `Build` menu and rebuild it.